# Docker healthcheck for nginx container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a project using the official `nginx` docker container from Docker Hub, launching via Docker Compose. I have healthchecks configured in Docker Compose for each of my containers, and recently the healthcheck for this `nginx` container has been behaving strangely; on launching with `docker-compose up -d`, all my containers launch, and begin running healthchecks, but the `nginx` container looks like it never runs the healthcheck. I can manually run the script just fine if I `docker exec` into the container, and the healthcheck runs normally if I restart the container.

Example output from `docker ps`:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                            PORTS                                                                       NAMES
458a55ae8971        my_custom_image           "/tini -- /usr/local…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes (healthy)                                                                                        project_worker_1
5024781b1a73        redis:3.2                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes (healthy)            127.0.0.1:6379->6379/tcp                                                    project_redis_1
bd405dde8ce7        postgres:9.6              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes (healthy)            127.0.0.1:15432->5432/tcp                                                   project_postgres_1
93e15c18d879        nginx:mainline            "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes (health: starting)   127.0.0.1:80->80/tcp, 127.0.0.1:443->443/tcp                                nginx
```

Example (partial, for brevity) output from `docker inspect nginx`:

```
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 11568,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2018-02-13T21:04:22.904241169Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Health": {
            "Status": "unhealthy",
            "FailingStreak": 0,
            "Log": []
        }
    },
```

The portion of the `docker-compose.yml` defining the `nginx` container:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx:mainline
  # using container_name means there will only ever be one nginx container!
  container_name: nginx
  restart: always
  networks:
    - proxynet
  volumes:
    - /etc/nginx/conf.d
    - /etc/nginx/vhost.d
    - /usr/share/nginx/html
    - tlsdata:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
    - attachdata:/usr/share/nginx/html/uploads:ro
    - staticdata:/usr/share/nginx/html/static:ro
    - ./nginx/healthcheck.sh:/bin/healthcheck.sh
  healthcheck:
    test: ['CMD', '/bin/healthcheck.sh']
    interval: 1m
    timeout: 5s
    retries: 3
  ports:
    # Make the http/https ports available on the Docker host IPv4 loopback interface
    - '127.0.0.1:80:80'
    - '127.0.0.1:443:443'
```

The `healthcheck.sh` I am loading in as a volume:

```
#!/bin/bash

service nginx status || exit 1
```

It looks like the problem is just an issue with systemd never returning from the status check when the container initially launches, and at the same time the configured healthcheck timeout does not trigger. Everything else works, and `nginx` is up and responding, but it would be nice for the healthcheck to function properly without needing to manually restart each time I start up.

Is there something missing in my configuration, or a better check I can run?

Comment: Have you checked `less /var/log/nginx/error.log`? What is showing after first `service nginx status`?

Comment: The `nginx` official image symlinks `error.log` to `/dev/stderr`, which is captured by Docker. So running `less /var/log/nginx/error.log` will not do what you expect. Regardless, yes, I have checked the log outputs, and there are no errors. As the question states, nginx launches and functions normally. The issue is the healthcheck script never runs; i.e. there is _no_ first `service nginx status` run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over a year later, I have found a solution. First, an additional clarification on the environment, what I believe is happening, and speculation on a possible bug with the Docker Engine.

The Compose file I am using now is launching a lightly modified version of the 'official' Alpine NGINX image, which uses `COPY` to load in the healthcheck script and adds `HEALTHCHECK` explicitly in the image. This image is used for an `nginx` service, and is used in concert with an image running [jwilder/docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) to use container metadata from Docker to generate NGINX configuration files. This container is running as a service named `nginx-gen`. When containers change, configuration is re-generated, and if there are any changes, a `SIGHUP` is sent to the `nginx` service.

What I discovered is the following:

- If all services are launched together, the `nginx` service never runs healthchecks;
- If the `nginx` service is restarted soon after launch, healthchecks complete normally;
- If the `nginx` service is launched by itself, healthchecks complete normally;
- If all services other than `nginx-gen` are launched together, healthchecks complete normally;
- If all services are launched together, but `nginx-gen` is modified to `sleep 60` before doing anything, healthchecks complete normally;

So, it appears that there is some obscure interaction with signal processing, Docker, and NGINX. If a `SIGHUP` is sent to an NGINX process in a container *before* the first healthcheck runs in that container, no healthchecks ever run.

The final iteration I came up with modifies the `nginx-gen` container to poll the health of the `nginx` container. It looks up the health status of a container with a defined label in a loop, with a short `sleep`. Once the `nginx` container reports healthy, `nginx-gen` proceeds to generate configuration files. I also changed the notification method to `docker exec` a script to explicitly test and reload configuration in the `nginx` container, rather than rely on `SIGHUP`.

End result: I can `docker-compose up -d`, and everything eventually reports `healthy` without further intervention. Success!

Comment: So for even more tl;dr, how did your nginx service in docker-compose look like in the end? And what was changed comparing to initial code samples?

Answer (score 23):

I think that there is no need for a custom script in this case.

Try just change your healthcheck test to

```
test: ["CMD", "service", "nginx", "status"]
```

That works fine for me.

Try to use `"` instead of `'` as well, just in case :)

**EDIT**

If you really want to force an `exit 1`, in case of failure, you could use:

```
test: service nginx status || exit 1
```

Comment: The custom script is necessary because the healthcheck mechanism expects a `0` exit status for healthy and a `1` exit status for unhealthy. `service` does not match these expectations, hence the script that forces a return of `1` for unhealthy.

Comment: Again, this is not a solution. The problem as far as I can tell is that the healthcheck for this container _never runs_ on first launch. It will only run if the container is manually restarted. It runs fine after restart. Also, using a string like your edit runs the healthcheck in a subshell, e.g. `sh -c 'service nginx status || exit 1'` which is not the right thing.

Comment: BTW, this does not work for the `alpine` version as `service` isn't a command.

Answer (score 11):

for the official alpine nginx image you can also do:

```
healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "wget -O /dev/null http://localhost || exit 1"]
      timeout: 10s
```

wget is part of the standard image. What this does is download your index.html/php/whatever to nowhere (/dev/null), and it should timeout and fail otherwise.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question. The problem was with healthchecks never running in the first place, not alternate ways to do a healthcheck.

Comment: `wget` is NOT part of official `nginx` image.

Comment: @TheGodfather I am currently using the nginx:1.19-alpine minimal image and it contains wget as well as curl. I implemented my test using `test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -so /dev/null http://localhost/ || exit 1"]` and it is working fine, however wget shows me (connection refused).

Comment: Small clarification: official `nginx:latest` images do NOT include wget while `nginx:alpine` includes it (that's weird, typically one would expect alpine to be somehow "subset" of full image)

Comment: This is not surprising once you know that Alpine is based on Busybox, which is a single binary that is the tool under whose name it is called. Sounds strange? Try `ls -l /usr/bin/` on Alpine. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I attempted the same script and encountered the same issue. I changed the `healthcheck.sh` to instead run like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

if service nginx status; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Running this in the docker container resulted in successful health checks.

Comment: Thanks, glad it's working for you; but, I do not think this is the correct solution. When I try this script, I still see the same behavior. The container is perpetually in starting state, and inspecting the container shows a health status of `unhealthy` with a `FailingStreak` value of 0. The healthcheck script simply never runs, regardless of content.